# How to GetCurrentMethod() for an inherited class function

Tags: c#, unit-testing, inheritance

I have built out a UI testing suite and framework that utilizes Selenium for testing. In my framework I utilize a BaseTest class that is inherited by the Test classes in order to simplify my SetUp and Teardown. In the base test I do a few things including starting the driver, initializing the logger, and maximizing the browser for functional testing.

My problem is that when I initialize the logger, I need to pass the logger a name. I am wanting to utilize the actual test's namespace plus the actual test name so I can filter through logs on individual tests to help diagnose issues with tests and with bugs as well.

This is how I currently have my base test set up:

```
[SetUp]
public void RemoteSetUp()
{
    string LoggerName = GetType().Namespace + "_" + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
    logger = LogManager.GetLogger(LoggerName);
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
    capabilities.AcceptInsecureCerts = true;
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://10.16.199.64:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();   
}
```

This is only doing half of what I want correctly. Where I declare the LoggerName it is returning the TEST'S namespace (not the base test's namespace) however the `System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();` is returning the BASE TEST'S method name. This causes my LoggerName to equal `[TestNamespace]_[BaseTestMethodName]`.

How can I make my LoggerName equal to `[TestNamespace]_[TestMethodName]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your BaseTest looks like. Here's how you get the underlying type. Note: I tested this with Nullable:

```
var t = typeof(BaseTest<int>);

if (t.GetType().IsGenericType &&
    t.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(BaseTest<>))
{
    var type = t.GetGenericArguments()[0];
}
```